# how to save utc time without offset in postgresql using django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, time, timezone

Hi im using django and in my one of the model i have

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

and settings.py file

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_TZ = True
```

using this date and time automatically saving PostgreSQL db in format of `2020-01-24 20:13:47.846445+05:30` with offset(+05:30) but i want to save it as

`2020-01-24 14:43:47.846445+00:00` **without offset** means as 00 but if inspect one instance `created_at` row data using

`python manage.py shell` i am getting required format(Django handling internally fine) so how to save date and time with offset `00:00` ?

what is tried is using manually assigned `timezone.now()`(its value is 2020-01-24 14:43:47.846445+00:00)  to updated_at but if i open PostgreSQL editor again showing same value as `2020-01-24 20:13:47.846445+05:30` instead of `2020-01-24 14:43:47.846445+00:00`

all of the above in local laptop but tried another way i hosted my django in production server with ip location(sever cloud server location) is india now my db showing correct result as `2020-01-24 14:43:47.846445+00:00` with offset `00` i dont know how

Comment: Do you have a real, legitimate need to do this? You are trying to override the default behavior of Postgres which can lead to unexpected things if you don't be careful: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#postgresql

Comment: @dfundako because i need save data from different country and time zone so i am thing making 00 is good to micro services and capability so front team from different country they will set 00 send send to backed

Comment: TZ are time/space indicators, +00:00 means you need to set a space within this time all year around as standard time, see them here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%C2%B100:00 I use greenland, but you should use the TZ where the server is living, django calculates automatically from where the user is requesting if setup to do so, your microservices should be aware of it as well, your api should be aware of it, if you decide to serve the naive datestamps, leave it as greenland and let clients to run the conversions.

Comment: What about a 2nd field that you populate on save that calculates the value with 00? I don't think you need this, but if you insist.

Comment: @panchicore i need to make server is independent of time zone

Comment: because users are in different places, you should store aware timezones placed in the +00:00 read more about [Naive and aware datetime objects][1]. if you decide to save without TZ, when the user saves, it will be hardcoded to the user's TZ and you don't want this, at least if explicitly need it then turn off the USE_TZ and postgres will just save without +00:00... I insist, your users/clients need this. 


  [1]: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects

Comment: @panchicore i want TZ but in 00 format but front end team will take current local time(ex 02:30 pm + 05:30)  calculate it and the will send 9:00:00+00:00 utc format this format i will save in db, how about making same thing for created and updated at